# how would i have one entry box display individual entries into different places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am essentially trying to have my entry box display the entered text on the screen as a label, expect after each time the button is pressed (the button that displays the text), the newly entered data is displayed somewhere else on the screen. Essentially multiple labels from one entry box and button.

```
def writelabel():
    labelentrval = Label(master, font = ("Helvetica", 15), text="" + str(entryvalue.get()))
    labelentrval.place(x=645,y=621)
    entryvalue.delete(first=0,last=22)
    
    ()


entryvalue = Entry(master)
entryvalue.place(x=700, y=515)

buttonpressy = Button(master,text="Enter", command=writelabel)
buttonpressy.place(x=845,y=510)
```

Code is above, and so far when I enter something into my entry box and press the button it displays it on the screen as a label. But how would I keep displaying my entries over and over in different places?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new label for every button press:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clicked():
    text = e.get()
    newLabel = Label(root, text=text)
    newLabel.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = Button(root, text='click', command=clicked)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```